# How to close a div on click in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, calendly

I have added a close button to a div in Calendly popup in VueJS and I want to close this div when click on the close button. How can I do this?

This is my Calendly Code:

```
<TransitionRoot as="template" :show="openTimes">
<Dialog
  as="div"
  class="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto"
  @close="closeModal"
  :open="openTimes"
  :initialFocus="closeModalTimesRef"
>
```

And this is the button I have added

```
<button type="button" class="close" 
@click="$emit('close')"> X 
 </button>
```

Comment: Do you want to close the popup?

Comment: Yes, sir, I want to close the popup when clicked in close button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the [v-if directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) (or other methods of conditional rendering available in the link).

Usually you set a key like: `showDialog: true` in your data/state object and add it to your dialog and catch the close event like so:

```js
<script>
  data() {
    return {
      showDialog: true;
    };
  },
</script>
<template>
  <dialog
    v-if="showDialog"
    @close="showDialog = false;"
  />
</template>
```

Comment: Is showModal and showDialog are same? Or should I use the both showModal and showDialog?

Comment: @tekbhatt I updated answer with correct variable. Hope it make sense now.

Comment: Sorry sir still doesn't work. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh yea, didn't realise i changed the name of the variable. This should work, if it doesn't im fairly certain its because your event doesn't get emitted as expected or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```js
<button onclick="showOrCloseDiv()">Click The Button</button>
<div id="thedivid">
JS tuto
</div>
<script>
   function showOrCloseDiv() {
      var v = document.getElementById("thedivid");
      if (v.style.display === "none") {
         v.style.display = "block";
      } else {
         v.style.display = "none";
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry sir still didn't work. Anyway thanks for your help.